# How can I get input and raw_imput functions to work in Python?

Tags: python, random

Whenever I use input and raw_imput in Python, it gives me an error report. Such as in the simple number guessing game. This is what happens:

```
>>> import random
>>> number= random.randint(1,100)
>>> guess= input("guess a number. ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'input' is not defined
```

The same thing happens when I use raw_input. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Just add the this in the first line `imput = input` assuming that you're using python 3 otherwise add `imput = raw_input`. :7

Answer (score 4):

"imput" is not a standard function in Python. Spell it like "input".

Comment: Sorry to be off-topic, but what did I do wrong in my post to get a downvote? (I want to know so I can answer better in future situations :))

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As far as I can tell, your answer is correct and did not deserve a down-vote. Also, I can see one up-vote and zero down-votes.

Answer (score 3):

You've misspelled input.  It should be **input** and **raw_input**, not imput and raw_imput.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the meaning and purpose of both `input()` and `raw_input()` have **changed** between Python 2 and Python 3.

### Python 2

- `input()` reads keyboard input *and* parses it as a Python expression (possibly returning a string, number, or something else)
- `raw_input()` reads keyboard input and returns a string (without parsing)

### Python 3

- `input()` reads keyboard input and returns a string
- `raw_input()` does not exist

To get similar behaviour in Python 3 as Python 2's `input()`, use `eval(input())`.

Comment: Did you notice that he had misspelled the word, and that the interpreter threw back that "imput" was not defined?

Comment: Yes, the other answers mentioned that. However, the question also does not state whether the OP is using Python 2 or Python 3, and this important difference often trips up beginners. If the OP has (clearly) never used the `input()` function before, it's good to know the differences between Python versions.

Comment: You should have mention that to use eval(input()) is not the best soultion.For python 3 use int(input()) or float(input())